# MVC ASP.NET not showing any results from database using join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have created an MVC application that is supposed to join two tables from a Database using LINQ; when the application is run there are no results showing. Additionally, I have viewed the inspect element in my browser, and no tables from my foreach loop are showing?

ViewModel.cs

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;

   namespace WorkingWithMultipleDataTables.Models
   {
       public class ViewModel
       {
           public Employee employee { get; set; }
           public Company companies { get; set; }
       }
   }
```

HomeController.cs

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Mvc;
   using WorkingWithMultipleDataTables.Models;

   namespace WorkingWithMultipleDataTables.Controllers
   {
       public class HomeController : Controller
       {
           // GET: Home
           public ActionResult Index()
           {
               using (Netmatters_reflection_dbEntities db = new Netmatters_reflection_dbEntities())
               {

                   List<Employee> employees = db.Employees.ToList();
                   List<Company> companies = db.Companies.ToList();
              
                   var employeeRecord = from e in employees
                                        join d in companies on e.EmployeeId equals d.CompanyId
                                        select new ViewModel
                                        {
                                            employee = e,
                                            companies = d,
                                        };
                   return View(employeeRecord);
                }
           }

       }
   }
```

Index.cshtml

```
   @model IEnumerable<WorkingWithMultipleDataTables.Models.ViewModel>
   @{
       Layout = null;
    }

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="bg-dark text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th>EmployeeId</th>
                    <th>First_Name</th>
                    <th>Last_Name</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>

                    <th>CompanyId</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Logo</th>
                    <th>Website</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.employee.EmployeeId</td>
                        <td>@item.employee.First_Name</td>
                        <td>@item.employee.Last_Name</td>
                        <td>@item.employee.Company</td>
                        <td>@item.employee.Email</td>
                        <td>@item.employee.Phone</td>

                        <td>@item.companies.CompanyId</td>
                        <td>@item.companies.Name</td>
                        <td>@item.companies.Email</td>
                        <td>@item.companies.Logo</td>
                        <td>@item.companies.Website</td>


                    </tr>

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I have debugged the application but no issues were found; when I build the application it shows a successful build ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have viewed the inspect element in my browser, and no tables from
> my foreach loop are showin

I have tried to reproduce your scenario but I am getting the data as expected. Furthermore, you might ended up with empty list if you haven't set [primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key) within your table and [POCO model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key).

I have tried in following way and getting expected result:

Database Table Design:

Company Table:

[image]

Employee Table:

[image]

POCO Model:

```cs
public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    }


public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Logo { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Db Context Class:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
     

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
           
        }
        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
       


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("CompanyTable");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("EmployeeTable");

        }
    }
```

**Note:** Please check if you configured your database context accordingly. You can [have a look our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#update-the-database-context).

Controller:

```cs
public class EmployeeCompanyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public EmployeeCompanyController( ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<EmployeeModel> employees = _context.Employees.ToList();
            List<CompanyModel> companies = _context.Companies.ToList();

            var employeeRecord = from e in employees
                                 join d in companies on e.CompanyId equals d.CompanyId
                                 select new ViewModel
                                 {
                                     employee =e,
                                     companies = d,
                                 };
            return View(employeeRecord);

        }
    }
```

**Note:** I have used your controller and view code exactly the same way. No change I made.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your join code you have `on e.EmployeeId equals d.CompanyId`. Shouldn't that be something like `on e.CompanyId equals d.CompanyId`, so that you match employees that work in a specific company?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).